# Can I backup my machine by just doing "cp -R / /pathToSSD"

Tags: linux, backup, data-recovery, storage, data

I want to completely backup my computer. I got a 1TB drive. Normally backing up is a whole process and I find it would be so easier to just copy the filesystem into the drive then in the event of my computer breaking or factory reset, I can just replace the file system with "mv" or something.

Would this work? I cant exactly test it right now. And I know this would not be the most space efficient way but this drive holds more than my computer and thats all I'd use this drive for.

Right now I use a Macbook on Monterey but also have a couple virtual machines(Kali, Ubuntu, Arch) that I want to backup as well. Would this method be viable?

Comment: if this is macos, why not use timemachine?

Answer (score 0):

Do not do it.

This command will copy thousands of useless transient files in `/dev`, `/proc`, `/sys`, `/run`, `/tmp`, and `/var`.

Are you sure you need your distro? By the time you want to restore your backup it will be outdated and not worth restoring. If that's the case, then simply `cp -a -r $HOME /pathToSSD`. I'd use rsync instead though, `rsync -av --progress --preallocate $HOME /pathToSSD`. The cp utility cannot preallocate files thus they may end up heavily fragmented. For an SSD it's no big deal but I still prefer files to lay on the disk sequentially.

Comment: I use `-aAXHSxPhW --sparse --force --fuzzy --delete` options for my root disk mirror, especially something like `-x` and `--sparse`  `--force` and `--delete` should be considered for any root disk mirror.  files like /var/log/lastlog can be huge if not mirrored with sparse.